# Google Visualization Spacing

Tags: charts, google-visualization

I have a chart similar to the one below using the Google Visualization API. My problem is that on the right side of where the key is for this chart(where it says low, medium, high) there is too much white space. How can I get rid of this white space?

[image]
<sub>(source: [securitymonks.com](http://blog.securitymonks.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/04/googlecolumn.png))</sub>

Comment: 3D plots are needlessly hard to read. Please be kind to your audience and use a 2D plot instead.

Comment: I am, the one pictured above is not the one I am using, it is just the closest image I could find to the one I am using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a kind of work around I ended up just making the graph wider and using overflow:hidden on the containing Div. If anyone knows if the API allows to make the white space smaller please let me know.

Answer (score 6):

You can play around with width and height percentages & width and height values in options variable and even push the legend to bottom as one single line.  Then pass the options to the chart you are drawing.

```
var options2 = { width: 265, height: 200,
            chartArea: { left: 60, top: 20, width: "100%", height: "60%" }, 
            isStacked: true, allowHtml: true, 'legend': 'bottom', titleTextStyle: { color: 'green', fontFamily: 'Arial', fontSize: 16 }, legendTextStyle: { color: '#666666' },
            vAxis: { title: 'Liters', titleTextStyle: { color: 'blue', fontName: 'Arial', fontSize: 10 }, textStyle: { fontSize: 9} },
```